# Does sp_indexoption cause index rebuilds?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, index, index-tuning

I want to switch `AllowRowLocks=ON` on a number of indexes. Some of those indexes are on large tables, and I don't really want to rebuild or reorganize the index.

It is not clear from [the MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186253.aspx) whether or not the index will be rebuilt.

As a secondary related part of this question, the MSDN article states that the use of this is being phased out and shouldn't be used anymore:

> This feature will be removed in the next version of Microsoft SQL
>   Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to
>   modify applications that currently use this feature. Instead, use
>   ALTER INDEX (Transact-SQL).

Looking at the [`ALTER INDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188388.aspx), it seems you are forced to rebuild or reorganize. Have I understood that correctly? Through `ALTER INDEX` can I just reset this row lock option?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under the covers `sp_indexoption` just does an `ALTER INDEX` as well.

My recommendation would be to forget about `sp_indexoption` and just utilize `ALTER INDEX`:

```
alter index IX_YourIndex
on dbo.YourTable
set
(
    allow_row_locks = on
);
go
```

As noted in the [BOL reference for `ALTER INDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188388.aspx), when you specify just the *set* options:

> Specifies index options without rebuilding or reorganizing the index

Comment: Would love to +1 twice!

Comment: Awesome, Thank you. The syntax on that MSDN page is rather meaty!

Comment: @Junto Glad to help :-) And yes for some of the more "robust" references they can be quite daunting with all of the syntax and information.